# I have a roblox leaderstats script with 3 IntValues in 2 different folders, but they don't save properly. I don't know what's wrong. I got no errors

Tags: save, roblox, datastore

here is the code

```
-- make sure to have a script inside of ServerScriptService.

local DataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("ValueSave")
local DataStore2 = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("ValueSave2")
local DataStore3 = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("ValueSave3")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local plrstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    plrstats.Name = "Stats"

    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Value = DataStore:GetAsync(plr.userId) or 0
    
    local Upgrade = Instance.new("IntValue", plrstats)
    Upgrade.Name = "Upgrade"
    Upgrade.Value = DataStore2:GetAsync(plr.userId) or 1
    
    local cost = Instance.new("IntValue", plrstats)
    cost.Name = "Cost"
    cost.Value = DataStore3:GetAsync(plr.userId) or 10
    
    if cost.Value < 10 then
        cost.Value = 10
    end
    
    if Upgrade.Value < 1 then
        Upgrade.Value = 1
    end

    cash.Changed:Connect(function()
        DataStore:SetAsync(plr.userId, cash.Value)
    end)
    
    Upgrade.Changed:Connect(function()
        DataStore2:SetAsync(plr.userId, Upgrade.Value)
    end)
    
    cost.Changed:Connect(function()
        DataStore3:SetAsync(plr.userId, cost.Value)
    end)
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    DataStore:SetAsync(plr.userId, plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value)
    DataStore2:SetAsync(plr.userId, plr.Stats.Upgrade.Value)
    DataStore3:SetAsync(plr.userId, plr.Stats.Cost.Value)
end)
```

I tried to debug but it didn't work
I tried it like a player would, not in roblox studio, and it didn't work again.
I don't understand why it doesn't, work because before i placed 2 of the IntValues in Stats and not leaderstats it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the userid property is `UserId`, not `userId`

This may be the reason you are experiencing issues with saving